# How to read two files together in Mule for merging

Tags: file, mule

I have a scenario where multiple files will be dropped at a location. I am interested in reading two files out of it as a pair (e.g., 913.xml and 913.pdf). I want to pass both files to a Java component which will merge them.

I know how to merge them but I am not sure how to pass two files at once to my Java component

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can think of two options:

- Configure the file inbound endpoint to select say the XML files and in your component use the [MuleClient](http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/3.4.0/apidocs/index.html?org/mule/api/client/MuleClient.html) to request the other file,
- Configure the file inbound endpoint to select both XML and PDF files and add a `collection-aggregator` configured with an `expression-message-info-mapping` that uses the `originalFilename` property in a correlation ID expression that extracts the file name *sans* extension from it. Don't forget to set the `MULE_CORRELATION_GROUP_SIZE` property to 2 before the aggregator.

Comment: I was thinking very similar to first option. You confirmed it, Thank you. Can you please elaborate on second option. I am not sure how to proceed with it

Comment: David, I applied your 1st option, `muleClient.request()`, payload returned is of type `payload=org.mule.transport.AbstractConnector$7`, how can I get file out of it

Comment: Isn't the payload a `java.io.InputStream`?

Comment: Nope, this is what I got: org.mule.DefaultMuleMessage{id=c313a3e5-f3c4-11e2-9e6b-53325817b820 payload=org.mule.transport.AbstractConnector$7 correlationId=<not set> correlationGroup=-1 correlationSeq=-1 encoding=UTF-8 exceptionPayload=<not set>
Message properties: INVOCATION scoped properties: INBOUND scoped properties: directory=C:\Images\forPolling fileSize=6584092     originalFilename=9354309-incorrect.pdf timestamp=1371238099743

}

Comment: Are you sure `org.mule.transport.AbstractConnector$7` is not an instance of `java.io.InputStream`? Have you checked?

Comment: I checked .getClass().getName()/simpleName() but guess its implemented as an anonymous class, even getSuperClass didn't return what i was hoping for. But yes instanceof  confirms its of type InputStream. Thank you. Is there a easy way to figure the underlying class

Comment: No need to, as far as you are concerned, it is an `InputStream` and that's the only interface you have to deal with.